# How to fix YCM printing "Use of undeclared identifier 'cout" or "No member named 'cout' in namespace 'std" in the Vim editor?

Tags: c++, vim

When I try to use the 'cout' func in a normal cpp-file. The ycm prints that error.

I have put 'using namespace std' in the head of this file, and when I want to use 'cout' func to print something, the YCM puts the error.
[image]

But if I switch to use the standard format to use 'cout' as 'std::cout', the YCM tells that 'No member...' error.
[image]

Here is my .ycm_extra_conf.py and I'm sure the  is included in the path with 'std' namespace containing func 'cout'.
[image]
[image]

And I have put the file in the ycm configuration.
But I don't know why it keeps printing that error. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What happens if you remove `using namespace std;`? (and use `std::cout`)

Comment: It will still show `No member named 'cout' in namespace 'std'`

Comment: Are the paths you've written in the configuration file the ones displayed by `clang++  -E -xc++ - -Wp,-v < /dev/null`? If not, they should.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the order of the flags, problem seems similar to the one in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/2885#issuecomment-360835891).

Comment: Great! This github issue is of help to me!!! Thanks a lot!!